# Scipy autotest finished with one error

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, autotest

Under Ubuntu 14.04 I installed python 2.76. then scipy as shown [here](http://www.scipy.org/install.html), namely through

> sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose

The `python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()"` test finishes with no error, but `python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"` results in:

```
======================================================================
```

### ERROR: test_fitpack.TestSplder.test_kink

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/tests/test_fitpack.py", line 333, in test_kink
    splder(spl2, 1)  # Should work
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py", line 1186, in splder
    "and is not differentiable %d times") % n)
ValueError: The spline has internal repeated knots and is not differentiable 1 times

---

Ran 8936 tests in 77.338s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=115, SKIP=191, errors=1)

What should I do?

Comment: This seems to have been fixed a couple of weeks ago: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/3673. Try using the development branch and see if the problems goes away (and if it does not, file a bug).